# Can i use a custom domain with free azurewebsites.net in Azure and can i also have a free ssl?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-webapps

I have a domain for example wwww.peterpan.com and also a free azurewebsite where i'm hosting my website called peterpan.azurewebsite.net

I would like to use my custom domain with the free azurewebsite so that if i go to [www.peterpan.com](http://www.peterpan.com) it will show peterpan.azurewebsite.net

Is this possible? Can i use a custom domain and map it to peterpan.azurewebsite.net?

Can I install install and configure a free ssl?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this is possible, see:
[Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)
and [Secure a custom DNS name with a TLS/SSL binding in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203). However, this is not included in the free tier.

Comment: Not possible with free tier.

Comment: Thank you @GauravMantri, I overread that part.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

You need at least Shared tier for a custom domain, and at least Basic tier to have HTTPS on that custom domain.
So you need Basic tier at minimum.

Comment: Thanks guys. Any links or resources/step by step tutorial  on how i can provision this - I'm currently on a free tier. Thanks